# Can't get php to output a form

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I'm trying to make a functional form with php. Initially i made an "index.html" file and another file called send.php. But it did't work. I also tried to insert "echo" in send.php and it worked! So i converted index.html into index.php and i put the php code inside of it before the body closing tag the tag , but it didn't work! So i realized that the error was in the code, but i copied these lines form the internet and i don't know php very well. Can someone help me? This is the code:

The name="" of the fields are correct, I checked.

```
<?php 
$name = ($_POST['name'];
$mail = ($_POST['mail'];
$budjet = ($_POST['budjet'];
$society = ($_POST['society'];
$message = ($_POST['message'];
$error = "Message sending failed";
$errorMessage = "Sorry your message can not be sent.";

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($mail)||empty($budjet)||empty($society)||empty($message)) 
{
    echo "Please fill al the fields";
    header('Location: index.html');
}
//validate against any email injection attempts
if(IsInjected($email))
{
    echo "Bad email value";
    header('Location: index.html');
}

$msg = "Name : $name \r\n"; 
$msg = "Mail : $mail \r\n";
$msg = "Budjet: $budjet \r\n";
$msg = "Society: $society \r\n";
$msg = "Message : ".stripslashes($_POST['message'])."\r\n\n";
$msg = "User information \r\n"; 
$msg = "User IP : ".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."\r\n"; 
$msg = "Browser info : ".$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]."\r\n"; 
$msg = "User come from : ".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];

$recipient = "myemail@mail.com"; // Change the recipient email adress to your adrees  
$sujet =  "Mail da Contact di Hindeto";
$mailheaders = "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n";

if (!$error){

        $sending = mail($recipient, $sujet, $msg, $mailheaders); 

        if ($sending) {
                // If the message is sent we output a string to use it 
                echo "Sent"; 
            } else {
                // Display Error Message
                echo $errorMessage; 
            }
    } else {
        echo $error; // Display Error Message
    }


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: You have some syntax errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have syntax error at first 5 lines remove  `(` before `$_POST`

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$budjet = $_POST['budjet'];
$society = $_POST['society'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

and after
  `header('Location: index.html');` and  `header('Location: index.html');`  print `exit();`

```
header('Location: index.html');
 exit();
```

Comment: Thank you! Before the correction the page wasn't even loading (there was a message = Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /index.php on line 277, but nothing else), now the page fully loads, but at the bottom appears both the echos "Please fill al the fields" and "Message sending failed", and the email doesn't arrive when i try.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jetawe, you must use isset() in validation statement.

```
$name = ((!isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name'])) ? null:$_POST['name']);
```